# How to make some columns editable but some not in bootstrap table？

Tags: html, django-rest-framework, bootstrap-table

I have a web app, front end has a bootstrap table, whose data rendered from Django rest framework.
As the data is rendered using data-field, it only has table header, does not have table column.

I want to make some some column editable but some not, but but failed to do so. The contenteditable='true'/'false' flag does not function on a column level.
How could I make some column editable but some not？

```
            <table  contenteditable='true' class="table table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"
               id="bk-table"
               data-toggle="table"
               data-toolbar="#toolbar"
               data-cookie="true"
               data-cookie-id-table="materialId"
               data-show-columns="true"
               data-show-refresh="true"
               data-show-fullscreen="true"
               data-height="650"
               data-click-to-select="true"
               data-id-field="id"
               data-show-footer="true"
               data-url="/api/materials/"
               data-query-params="queryParams"
               data-remember-order="true"
               data-pagination="true"
               data-side-pagination="client"
               data-total-field="count"
               data-data-field="results">
            <thead class="thead-dark" >
            <tr contenteditable='true'>
                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>                   
                <th data-field="type">Course Type</th>                 

            </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap table plugin ["x-editable"](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/editable/) to make a column editable or non-editable use
`data-editable="true"`  `data-editable="false"` respectively on `<tr>`

for example

```
<table id="my_table_id"
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
    <th class="col-md-4" data-editable="true">Name</th>
    <th class="col-md-7" data-editable="false">Description</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Tried, failed. When I use your method, all of the columns become non-editable